# Expression to find Holiday in SSIS

Tags: ssis

Trying to find a way to show in SSIS if a date falls on a Holiday to return true and if it is not on a holiday return false.

My thought was that I would just hardcode all of the holidays like for 0101 return true and for valentine day 0214 return true.

I was wondering if there was an easier way or a function that I had overlooked.

any assistance would be great! Thanks!

Comment: No. Holidays are different everywhere and are on different days each year. They can be rearranged by governing bodies (well in Australia anyway). The standard (and proven) pattern is to create a calendar table and define holidays in there (along with other useful calendar info).

Comment: Is valentines day a holiday?

Comment: Holidays will be different based on countries. To achieve your logic you can create a lookup table which stores the Holidays and use the SSIS tools ex: Lookup to check the table whether the particular date falls on a holiday or not. Please maintain the Holiday list table as years pass.